# Access Denied while trying to enable versioning of an AWS s3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to enable versioning for a s3 bucket using boto3 but got the error below

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketVersioning operation: Access Denied

This issue is similiar with below issue which was resolved
[AWS: Boto3 Enable S3 Versioning/Lifecycle - Access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135726/aws-boto3-enable-s3-versioning-lifecycle-access-denied)

However, My situation is different with above issue

I tried to make sure if I have enough permission to enable bucket versioning via below AWS CLI command and succeeded

> $ aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket  --versioning-configuration Status=Enabled

Below is my code snippet for reference

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket_version = s3.BucketVersioning(bucket)
bucket_version.enable()
```

I also tried to call run the AWS CLI command via os.system() call in python code directly but got the same Access Denied error message

```
os.system("aws s3api put-bucket-versioning --bucket" + " " + bucket + " " + "--versioning-configuration Status=Enabled")
```

Again, I am sure I have configured correct access key and credentials in AWS configuration and verified via AWS CLI command

Could someone help comment if I could do anything further on this issue?

Appreciated

Comment: 1) Try your CLI again but with `Status=Enabled` so that you are testing the same two examples. 2) Check what IAM user you are `aws iam get-user`. Does this match what you expect? 3) Check your Access Key ID: `aws configure get aws_access_key_id`.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley. 1) It should be "Status=Enabled". Just a typo and I had fixed. 2) User is correct and I assigned Admin previledge to it already 3) the access key id is correct. It's the same with what had been configured in aws credential file and the one belonged to the expected user